# How to get XML node names without namespace in java?

Tags: java, xml

I have an xml file having data which looks like given below:

```
 ....
 <ems:MessageInformation>
        <ecs:MessageID>2147321820</ecs:MessageID>
        <ecs:MessageTimeStamp>2016-01-01T04:38:33</ecs:MessageTimeStamp>
        <ecs:SendingSystem>LD</ecs:SendingSystem>
        <ecs:ReceivingSystem>CH</ecs:ReceivingSystem>
        <ecs:ServicingFipsCountyCode>037</ecs:ServicingFipsCountyCode>
        <ecs:Environment>UGS-D8UACS02</ecs:Environment>
</ems:MessageInformation>
....
```

There are many other nodes also. All nodes have namespace like ecs,tns,ems etc. I am suing following code part to extract all node names without namespace.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException, TransformerException {

        DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = docBuilder.parse(new File("C:\\Users\\DadMadhR\\Desktop\\temp\\EDR_D3A0327.XML"));

        NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = nodeList.item(i);
            //System.out.println(node.getNodeName());
            System.out.println(node.getLocalName());
        }
}
```

But when I execute this code, it's printing null for individual node. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

I read on internet and I came to know that node.getLocalName() will give node name without namespace. What is wrong then in my case?

Comment: look at this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/readingXML.html

Comment: For nodes of any type other than ELEMENT_NODE and ATTRIBUTE_NODE and nodes created with a DOM Level 1 method, such as Document.createElement(), this is always null

Comment: better check the node type first,  and then use the method

Answer (score 5):

You need to set the document builder factory to be namespace aware first. Then `getLocalName()` will start returning non-null values.

```
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
docBuilder.setNamespaceAware(true);   // <=== here
Document document = docBuilder.parse(new File("C:\\Users\\DadMadhR\\Desktop\\temp\\EDR_D3A0327.XML"));
```